# Web interface: creating edge between multiple collections

Tags: arangodb

Using the web interface how do I create an edge collection that links multiple (i.e. more than 2 different) vertex collections?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Just learned that this is specified in the Graph Settings.

Comment: Note that you can store references to documents in arbitrary collections in the `_from` and `_to` attributes of an edge, and also traverse these without defining a named graph: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#working-with-collection-sets